# Display position .css wrong with IE8 but Chrome is fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, internet-explorer-8

I use wordpress theme and try to add  to edit class but it doesn't work still wrong position in IE8.
And in the `<head>` i have this

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

In my theme it has a html5.js to work with IE but it what i said The position of sidebar and nav-menu are wrong.

You can look my site at tkmultiply.com

Comment: Please provide HTML and CSS within your question or create a JSFiddle, so that you question and answers will be helpful to others in the future

Answer (score 0):

just tested a little with IE7. The correct position of your menu bar should be if you're trying around with the CSS class:

```
.site-main .sidebar-inner {
 width: ....
}
```

When I disabled the width property in developer console (you can reach this with F11 in your IE), the position was just okay for me.